# Regex for reverse DNS entry

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to validate text field if it matches this kind of pattern for reverse DNS purpose

I tried `^\d+[^.*]|\.\d+|-in.addr.arpa.$`

```
93    
93.12   
93.32.12 
93.32.12.10-in.addr.arpa.  
www.domain.com   
www  
domain..983
```

but it matches the last one which is wrong it should match only the first 4 examples

Here is my rule

```
function check_record_NPTR(field){
    var regex = /^\d+[^.*]|\.\d+|-in.addr.arpa.$/;
    if(!regex.test(field.value)){
        highlight(field,true);
        return false;
    }
    else{
        highlight(field,false);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide us the rule you try to achive in this regex

Comment: Your regex says: The string either begins with at least one number, followed by one character, that is neither a dot, nor an asterisk. Or it contains a dot, followed by at least one number. Or it ends with the string "-in" + any char + "addr" + any char + "arpa" + any char. --- Im sure that is not what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: I added the rule in my first post 
Thank you

Comment: Am I wrong or make `[^.*]` not realy sense? It means "not **^** any character **.** with any occurrence **\*** "

Comment: @Marcus/ A dot inside a character class means a dot. same for asterisk. So it means not a dot or an asterisk.

Comment: I am a noob with regex so you must be right I am trying using an online checker to have what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you want to use instead is: `^(?:(?:\d+\.)*\d+(?:-in\.addr\.arpa\.)?)$`

It will select each entry that starts with a number or a list of numbers seperated by dots, that optionally ends on the string -in.addr.arpa.

A good source to learn regex by experimenting is [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) in my experience.

To make that sufficient for a reverse DNS purpose you should read into how to limit the quantity of numbers in each number and add it to the regex. There is a ton of documentation about this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help